# Homology and Algebraic homology

Tags: terminology, homological-algebra

Is there any difference between Homology and Homological Algebra as fields of mathematics or they are the same topic? If they are different, then is there also something called Algebraic Homology?!

Comment: "homology" is not a field. homology is something you can compute when you have a chain complex, and (roughly) the study of homology is called "homological algebra"

Comment: There is something called "Algebraic Topology" using homology and cohomology.

Answer (score 1):

Homology theory is part of [homological algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homological_algebra), using chain complexes to define homology groups. The Wikipedia page gives a nice survey here. The homology groups of a chain complex $(C_{\bullet},d_{\bullet})$ are denoted by $H_{n}((C_{\bullet},d_{\bullet}))$. Dually, we have the cohomology groups $H^n ((C_{\bullet},d_{\bullet}))$. Homological algebra plays a role in many other fields of mathematics, like *Algebraic topology*, *Number Theory*, *Group Theory*, *Algebraic geometry*, etc.